# tf.data.Dataset.filter(function) cannot access the directory

Tags: python, tensorflow

so i am trying to balance the dataset by removing the extra images from the each label.

First i am getting count for each label, and finding the minimal value of images per label, after that we need to create filter function to remove the extra images

```py
def filter_dataset(image, label):
    print(label_counts)
    def decrement_count(label):
        label_counts[label] -= 1

    count = label_counts[label]
    filter_condition = count <= label_count_min

    if filter_condition:
        tf.py_function(decrement_count, [label], [])
    
    return filter_condition

filtered_dataset = dataset.filter(filter_dataset)
```

this is error i am getting.

```py
TypeError: in user code:

    File "/tmp/ipykernel_13/1671532342.py", line 6, in filter_dataset  *
        count = label_counts[label]

    TypeError: Tensor is unhashable. Instead, use tensor.ref() as the key.
```

basically i cannot access keys by labels, how can this be fixed?

Comment: The solution is already in the error message. To be a key, a datatype has to be hash-able, and tensors are not. Use `label_counts[label.ref()]` (and also in other parts where you use tensors as keys).

Comment: it gives me this error
`
KeyError: in user code:

    File "/tmp/ipykernel_13/1064388637.py", line 7, in filter_dataset  *
        count = label_counts[label.ref()]

    KeyError: <Reference wrapping <tf.Tensor 'args_1:0' shape=() dtype=int32>>
`

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by converting the TensorFlow tensor to a Python scalar value before using it as a dictionary key. Use .numpy() to extract the scalar value from the TensorFlow tensor.

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Assuming label_counts is a Python dictionary
label_counts = {'label1': 10, 'label2': 15, 'label3': 8}
label_count_min = min(label_counts.values())

def filter_dataset(image, label):
    print(label_counts)

    def decrement_count(label):
        label_counts[label.numpy()] -= 1  # Convert TensorFlow tensor to Python scalar

    count = label_counts[label.numpy()]  # Convert TensorFlow tensor to Python scalar
    filter_condition = count <= label_count_min

    if filter_condition:
        tf.py_function(decrement_count, [label], [])

    return filter_condition

filtered_dataset = dataset.filter(filter_dataset)
```

Comment: I am getting the error:

```

AttributeError: in user code:

    File "/tmp/ipykernel_13/3516650905.py", line 7, in filter_dataset  *
        count = label_counts[label.numpy()]  # Convert TensorFlow tensor to Python scalar

    AttributeError: 'SymbolicTensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```